# Packaging multiple applications together

Tags: deployment, blackberry

I have a project that requires me to add another application to the package.
This application will act as a proxy, such as the one described in the `BBMSDKDemoProxy` sample project. I'd like the user to be able to download one package, both applications are installed, and my main application is launched via the proxy.

The problem is that I don't know exactly what steps to follow to achieve this. The project will be distributed via the app world, but I'd like to know how to do this via a website too.

I've found a link stating that you simply add both applications in a single .zip and upload that to the app world, but I want to be sure about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: exactly I don't know but I know making a library project and using it in another main project cause the same effect you want.

Comment: [Mr Smith's answer is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17670842/119114), but to add a couple of reference links, see [this one specifically concerning the proxy app](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BBM-SDK-Dependency-Checker-Packaging-the-proxy-and-app-together/td-p/1271425) and [this one, concerning OTA cod/jad distribution, too](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Deploying-multiple-cod-files-with-a-single-jad-file/td-p/54623).

Comment: preetam's solution would be very nice, but I can't seem to get it working. The app compiles and runs fine, but when it comes time to send a message via bbm nothing happens.

I can't show any ui from the library call. Even `system.out.print` messages seem to be ignored. Try catch doesn't reveal exceptions either. Strange

Comment: @Turdnugget You can have two regular projects in a workspace and add one as a dependency to the other (right click over main project -> Java build path -> projects tab). The eclipse plugin takes care of including all dependency projects when you build the main one.

Comment: I'm so certain that was the first thing I tried before questing down the multiple package road. But it works, so it was must've been a keyboard/chair error. Thanks a ton guys :)

Comment: I find that if i include the project, the library works but doesn't let the app start if BBM isn't on the device. If I export the lib as a jar, i can launch the app in both instances but the call to the library doesn't work anymore :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **For AppWorld**: just include the extra cod file in the file set to be uploaded. If you are uploading a zip then include the extra cod in the zip content.
- **For Desktop/BES**: you can include the cod file along the other files and manually edit the .alx to add an entry for the new module. I'd not recommend doing this unless you have a good understanding of the alx format and the different elements in the descriptor.
- **For OTA downloads**: You'd place the new cod file with the other cod files (if it contained sibling cods you'd publish the siblings instead). Then you can manually edit the .jad file to add the new module(s).

Of these 3 options, only the first one is safe. Manually editing the alx or jad is tricky, and is very easy to make mistakes. If you need files for desktop-BES or OTA installs I'd add a new library project as @preetam has suggested in the comments.